# My Galaxy Nexus can't connect to unsecured web using wi-fi at home

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus

My Samsung Galaxy Nexus can't connect to unsecured web using wi-fi at home.

I have to edit the url with `https://` to load the webpage. Some pages work but most of them just won't load.

Comment: Do other devices use this WiFi successfully?  Or use the uplink from this WiFi successfully?  Do you get an immediate error with http:// links, or does it time out?

Comment: Yes other wifi device (laptops/iphone) works well on this connection or configuration. No error messages, just blank white page and when I enter www.google.com the download indicator bar just stops somewhere in the middle and I then have to edit http to https to load the page.

Comment: It appears that the nexus browser has been set to only HTTPS browsing allowed over wifi. Opera browser works fine in wifi connection and no problem with all the browsers using 3G connection.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue ain't related with Browser APP, it's a Network configuration regarding the proxy settings.

As you can read from your phone's user manual on page 63:

> Proxy settings are used by Browser but may not be used by other apps.

---

Since you've mentioned that only "Browser" gets affected, and that all of them work fine under 3G, this leaves us with an WiFi settings issue:

1. Touch the "Settings" icon;
2. Touch "Wireless & networks" > "Wi-Fi";
3. Touch & hold your network in the list of Wi-Fi networks;
4. Touch "Modify network" in the dialog that opens;
5. Select "Show advanced option";
6. touch "None" under Proxy Settings, then touch "Manual" in the
   menu that opens.
7. Clear the proxy box, make sure nothing stays there.
8. Touch Save.

Open the browser and give it a try. You should now be able to navigate without problems either with `http` and `https`.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried to follow [Zuul answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26620/368284) but for me after selecting Manual Save button is disabled.

I was able to explicitly open sign-in page by following suggestion from https://9to5google.com/2015/12/18/heres-how-to-manually-access-a-public-wifi-login-page-on-android/

> If you head in browser to 192.168.1.1, the most common default router IP address,
> I’ve found that nine times out of ten I’m immediately redirected to
> the login page.